# Self-Similar Reverse-Sum Sequences

Tags: pattern-recognition, reverse-math

When a number is added to its reverse (digits in reverse order), sum it.

For example:

> 102 + 201 = 303
>
> 508 + 805 = 1313
>
> 246 + 642 = 888

Given all numbers between 0 and 10^9, discover the pattern to generate them without calculate all (only unique).

**Solution idea**

For 0 to 9, just calculate it all.

For remaining values, think as below. you don't need to build the table, but use the concept.

Setup a table for value of same number of digits (let number of digit be r)
size: 9 column with 10^(r-1) row
value distribution: Top left corner is the smallest of that digit part, plus one when moving down, plus 10^(r-1) when moving right

> 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
>
> 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91
>
> 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 99

Looking at this table, you will observe the result of any value will be same as the result as the one on its top right position (upward by 1 and right by 1).

In this sense, you should be able to see for digit r table, the count can be calculated by looking up result of values on first column and last row and then for each result calculated times a correct counter (number of values in its diagonal in point 2, values between 1 to 9)

> (result of 10) * 1
>
> (result of 11) * 2
>
> (result of 12) * 3
>
> (result of 13) * 4
>
> (result of 14) * 5
>
> (result of 15) * 6
>
> (result of 16) * 7
>
> (result of 17) * 8
>
> (result of 18) * 9
>
> (result of 19) * 9
>
> (result of 29) * 8
>
> (result of 39) * 7
>
> (result of 49) * 6
>
> (result of 59) * 5
>
> (result of 69) * 4
>
> (result of 79) * 3
>
> (result of 89) * 2
>
> (result of 99) * 1

But I realized that numbers with three, four, and so on. It's using the same pattern at all. I'm still missing more things which I'm not able to see.

Comment: By " discover the pattern to generate them without calculate all (only unique)" do you mean that we are supposed to make a list of all the numbers that can be the result of the reverse and add process on numbers less than $10^9$?  The last box seems to indicate we also have to determine how many numbers can be the source of each result.  Please make clear what you are asking.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, it is. I realized that if you calculate all numbers, there're repeated several times and they're following a pattern.

Comment: That is correct, but I still don't understand what result you are looking for.

Comment: An explanation or concept about how is the behavior of numbers from 10 to 100, 100 to 1000,  and so on (until 10^8 to 10^9). I say this because I'm creating a software calculating all numbers but it takes too mucho time (one hour). I would know if there's a formula or explanation without re-generate all the numbers.

The last block is the explanation I have for numbers 10 to 100, as you can see, only generating 18 numbers instead of 90 (100 - 90). Thus, my program can improve its performance with this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the problem algebraically?

$(a*10^2 + b*10 + c) + (c*10^2 + b*10 + a) = ???$

Then consider what conditions must be placed on a,b,c so that the sum is self-similar. On the flip side, what conditions must be true for a self-similar number to be a reversed sum? Can 101 be the result of a reversed sum? Why is it impossible?